# Is there a log for api requests to Desire2Learn LMS?

Tags: api, logging, desire2learn

With Desire2Learn's REST APIs, how do you see a log of the calls that are made to the APIs? There is nothing in the debug log table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no dedicated log for api calls. To see what your app is calling you have to use the web server log and filter by `/d2l/api/*`. [See](http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/wiki/LFDebugTest). If there is a fault or error with the parameters to the call it may show up in the debug log table, but doesn't show anything for normal operations.